# universal xcode 3.2.6 Landscape mode by default

Tags: objective-c, xcode3.2, ios-universal-app

How can i create universal apps using xcode 3.2.6 in Landscape mode bydefault?I need seprate .xib files for each view,Is i have to use this code
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
        {// Return YES for supported orientations
            return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape);
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this sample code and for making its View based i just hide its Navigation bar by using this code
`self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;`
in the RootViewController_Phone.h and in RootViewController_Pad 
[BenellingsonPost](http://benellingson.blogspot.in/2010/04/missing-ipad-app-template.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your plist, you should change `supported interface orientations` to just two items :

Item 0 `Landscape (right home button)`

Item 1 `Landscape (left home button)`

And use in each view controller:

```
  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   // Return YES for supported orientations
   return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation));
}
```